# EntityFramework SaveChanges() method duplicates rows in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have a problem with EF, when I call SaveCanges() method it inserts new rows to DB 2 times. Here is my code:

```
private void addTagsToTagger(FormCollection form)
{

        char[] delimiter = { ',' };
        List<string> userTags = form["tags"].Split(delimiter).ToList();
        List<Tagger> newItems = new List<Tagger>();
        List<Tagger> changedItems = new List<Tagger>();

        foreach (var tagItem in userTags)
        {
            Tagger tagger = new Tagger() { imageId = Int16.Parse(form["imgId"]), tag = tagItem.ToLower().Trim(), tagCount = 1 };
            Tagger taggerRow;
            using(var ctx = new vestibulyContext())
            {
                taggerRow = ctx.Tagger.FirstOrDefault(t => t.tag == tagger.tag);
            }
            if (taggerRow == null)
            {
                newItems.Add(tagger);
            }

        }

        if (newItems.Count() > 0)
        {
            using (vestibulyContext ctx = new vestibulyContext())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < newItems.Count(); i++)
                {
                    ctx.Tagger.Add(newItems[i]);
                }
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

        }

}
```

I don't know what is the problem with this. Thanks for comments.

Update 1: A little bit I rewrote my code but it isn't working. I don't know what is the problem, because it would be only a simple INSERT query. In num variable is always the number of items, which are added to context, but EF saves items duplicately into DB. (It's hard to learn a new framework...)

```
    private void addTagsToTagger(FormCollection form)
    {

        char[] delimiter = { ',' };
        List<string> userTags = form["tags"].Split(delimiter).ToList();

        var ctx = new vestibulyContext();
        for (int i = 0; i < userTags.Count(); i++)
        {
            if(!IssetTagInDb(userTags[i]))
            {
                ctx.Tagger.Add(new Tagger() { imageId = Int16.Parse(form["imgId"]), tag = userTags[i].ToLower().Trim(), tagCount = 1 });
            }
        }
        var num = ctx.SaveChanges();

    }

    private bool IssetTagInDb(string tag)
    {
        using (var ctx = new vestibulyContext())
        {
            Tagger taggerRow = ctx.Tagger.FirstOrDefault(t => t.tag == tag.ToLower().Trim());
            if (taggerRow == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `userTags` doesn't contain duplicate values?

Answer (score 0):

```
taggerRow = ctx.Tagger.FirstOrDefault(t => t.tag == tagger.tag);
```

you are tracking those entities i think !

so here there are two entities tracked each time

```
foreach (var tagItem in userTags)
    {
        Tagger tagger = new Tagger() { imageId = Int16.Parse(form["imgId"]), tag = tagItem.ToLower().Trim(), tagCount = 1 };
        Tagger taggerRow;
```